# Try Catch inside a catch block not working correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use a try-catch block inside a catch block. But it doesn't seem to work correctly.

After failing the parent try block the code goes to the nested catch block directly without performing the try function.

```
try {
    doSomeAsyncAction()
} catch (e1) {
    console.log("error 1")
    try {
        reverseAsyncAction()
    } catch (e2) {
        console.log("error 2")
    }
}
```

The results will be

```
error 1
error 2
```

Is there any limitation in JavaScript for nested try-catch blocks inside catch block?

Comment: Try **catch ()** without exception **catch (e1)** to **catch ()**

Comment: Add a `console.log('here')` before the call to `reverseAsyncAction()`, you'll see it will get called.

Comment: @Karthikcbe `} catch() {` is a syntax error. Did you mean `} catch {`?

Comment: You mention that those are `AsyncAction`s. Shouldn't you be `await`ing them then?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can have a catch inside a catch clause.
You may have two catch clauses one above, beneath the other, as such:

```
try{
}
catch{
}
catch{
}
```

I'm thinking of Java when I say this, but I think JavaScript is similar..

Comment: I think this is not possible in JS

Comment: No, this isn't possible in JS, and you _can_ have a catch inside a catch clause.